# Eigenvalues and power of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Knowing that matrix$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-6&7\\-14&15 \end{pmatrix}$$has eigenvalues $1$ and $8$, find an $2\times2$ matrix $B$ such that $B^3=A$.

Usually when I see a question, I would know what the question what me to show. But in this case, I have no clue except this is not a question to be solved by calculation. Can somebody give me some hints? What eigenvalues have to do with this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, each with multiplicity $1$, we can have the spectral decomposition of $A$ as,
$$A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1},$$
where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ and $Q$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $A$.

Now if we can find a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D^3 = \Lambda$, then we can let $B = Q D Q^{-1}$ and as a result,
$$B^3 = (Q D Q^{-1})(Q D Q^{-1})(Q D Q^{-1}) = QD(Q^{-1}Q)D(Q^{-1}Q)DQ^{-1}=QD^3Q^{-1} = A.$$

Do you know how to find such a matrix $D$?

Comment: Thanks. I realise what mistake I have made.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $AB=BA$ and that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues. Then $B$ is a polynomial in $A$, that is $B=\alpha I_2+\beta A$. We seek a real matrix $B$. Necessarily, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $1=1^{1/3},2=8^{1/3}$. Since $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, $\alpha +\beta=1,\alpha+8\beta=2$ and (mental calculation !) $\beta=1/7,\alpha=6/7$; we are done.